# spinner in .Net Core Angular 5 typescript

Tags: typescript, .net-core, angular5

I attempted to implement the typescript spinner component/service as defined here ( [How to do loading spinners, the Angular 2+ way](http://www.codetunnel.io/how-to-do-loading-spinners-the-angular-2/) ) in .Net Core 2 / Angular 5.

when the page loads that contains the spinner tag:

```
<spinner name="skuLoadSpinner" [(show)]="showSpinner"></spinner>
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'show' since it isn't a known property of 'spinner'. ("ft;width:50%;">
          <label for="power">SKU</label>
          <spinner name="skuLoadSpinner" [ERROR ->][(show)]="showSpinner"></spinner>
          <select style="" class="form-control" id="sku"
        "): ng:///AppModule/SkuRegistrationComponent.html@125:41
'spinner' is not a known element:
1. If 'spinner' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. To allow any element add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component.
```

Here is my current spinner.service.ts:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { SpinnerComponent } from './spinner.component';

@Injectable()
export class SpinnerService {
  private spinnerCache = new Set<SpinnerComponent>();

  _register(spinner: SpinnerComponent): void {
    this.spinnerCache.add(spinner);
  }

  show(spinnerName: string): void {
    this.spinnerCache.forEach(spinner => {
      if (spinner.name === spinnerName) {
        spinner.show = true;
      }
    });
  }

  hide(spinnerName: string): void {
    this.spinnerCache.forEach(spinner => {
      if (spinner.name === spinnerName) {
        spinner.show = false;
      }
    });
  }

  showGroup(spinnerGroup: string): void {
    this.spinnerCache.forEach(spinner => {
      if (spinner.group === spinnerGroup) {
        spinner.show = true;
      }
    });
  }

  hideGroup(spinnerGroup: string): void {
    this.spinnerCache.forEach(spinner => {
      if (spinner.group === spinnerGroup) {
        spinner.show = false;
      }
    });
  }

  showAll(): void {
    this.spinnerCache.forEach(spinner => spinner.show = true);
  }

  hideAll(): void {
    this.spinnerCache.forEach(spinner => spinner.show = false);
  }

  _unregister(spinnerToRemove: SpinnerComponent): void {
    this.spinnerCache.forEach(spinner => {
      if (spinner === spinnerToRemove) {
        this.spinnerCache.delete(spinner);
      }
    });
  }
}
```

And here is my spinner.component.ts file:

```
import { Component, Input, OnInit, EventEmitter, Output, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
import { SpinnerService } from './spinner.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'spinner',
  template: `
    <div *ngIf="show">
      <img *ngIf="loadingImage" [src]="loadingImage" />
      <ng-content></ng-content>
    </div>
  `
})
export class SpinnerComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  @Input() name: string;
  @Input() group: string;
  @Input() loadingImage: string;
  @Input() show = false;

  constructor(private spinnerService: SpinnerService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    if (!this.loadingImage) throw new Error("Spinner must have a loadingImage supplied.");

    this.spinnerService._register(this);
  }

  private isShowing = false;

  @Input()
  get show(): boolean {
    return this.isShowing;
  }

  @Output() showChange = new EventEmitter();

  set show(val: boolean) {
    this.isShowing = val;
    this.showChange.emit(this.isShowing);
  }

  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.spinnerService._unregister(this);
  }
}
```

Comment: You can't bind to the `show` property because it's commented out in your spinner component.

Comment: Sorry about that, I was trying something, and meant to uncomment it before posting the question here.  I get the same error message with it uncommented.

Comment: Only partially true, uncommenting it results in a duplicate due to the getter/setter:

  @Input()
  get show(): boolean {
    return this.isShowing;
  }

  @Output() showChange = new EventEmitter();

  set show(val: boolean) {
    this.isShowing = val;
    this.showChange.emit(this.isShowing);
  }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest putting the `Input()` decorator on the 'setter' instead of the 'getter'. While both are valid, putting it on the getter means you *could* run into issues if you (for some reason) had a different name for the setter.

I recommend changing to:

```
  get show(): boolean {
    return this.isShowing;
  }

  @Input()
  set show(val: boolean) {
    this.isShowing = val;
    this.showChange.emit(this.isShowing);
  }
```

Also, delete the `show` field as it is not even ever being set since you have added `isShowing` as a field.

Edit 1:

You will also need to ensure that you have imported and declared the spinner component in your `Module`. Go to whichever `Module` you are working in (most likely `AppModule` if you haven't created a shared one).

Add the import statement at the top and then also in the `declarations` array of the `Module`.

Edit 2:

As @littleGreenDude pointed out, also add the import statement for the `SpinnerService` there too, but put it in the `providers` array instead of the `declarations` array. This registers the service to the Angular DI (Dependency Injection) container so that it knows to initialise it so other components can have it injected into them.

Comment: What should it look like in the html?  I had this:

<spinner name="skuLoadSpinner" [(show)]="showSpinner"></spinner>

and then tried it with removing [(show)]="showSpinner"

However, this produces a different error:

Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:
'spinner' is not a known element:
1. If 'spinner' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. To allow any element add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component.

Comment: The HTML looks fine to me (assuming that `showSpinner` is a valid variable). Please see my edited post.

Comment: Also, as a friendly suggestion: Be very careful when following tutorials written for old versions of Angular. In this case it is not *too* bad, but in others you will end up in a lot of pain due to how different things can be.

Comment: Awesome!  Thank you for all the help.  Your solution got me there.  For completeness, there was one last thing I needed to add.  I had to add the SpinnerService to the providers in app.module.ts.  Without doing this, I was getting the following error;  core.js:1448 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[SpinnerComponent -> SpinnerService]: 
  StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[SpinnerComponent -> SpinnerService]: 
    NullInjectorError: No provider for SpinnerService!

Comment: I am delighted to hear that your problem is resolved. Well spotted with the service, I missed that one. I will update my answer to include this (for the sake of completeness also).